# What tools will help me remove an object from a toilet's siphon jet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

My toilet has discontinued Korky flapper, which is designed with a plastic ring that clips to the bottom of the flapper's air cavity.  Today, this plastic ring separated and is now resting at the bottom of the toilet inside the siphon jet, which is causing the toilet to not flush properly (no siphoning power, i.e. whooshing).

The ring is too large to pull through the siphon jet hole, though the plastic is malleable.  I've been trying to break the ring, and to force it through the hole with no luck.  I think I might need to try to melt the ring with a soldering iron, but only after I've pumped out all the standing water.

What other techniques or tools are available to help remove obstructions in the siphon jet?

Comment: I found a way to remove the ring yesterday evening.  As there wasn't much space to work with, a small coat hanger hook wasn't able to grab the ring as desired.  I was able to pin the ring down with coat hanger wire and cut it with a sharp blade.  I made a couple of cuts along the circumference as I wasn't able to completely cut through the diameter.  Then, grabbing with pliers, I could force the ring through the siphon jet hole -- the cuts allowed the ring to fold in half on its way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option #1 is always the best: use a coat hanger with a hook bent on the end.**

As a second option, hemostats are pretty handy, but may not be strong enough to break plastic. But perhaps it will help you hold the ring while you cut it with an exacto-knife or some wire nippers.

[image]

If you drain the water out, then you will be able to use something like [a hot knife](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=na7pJqbyOQY)... or just use a blow torch to easily heat a blade or a coat hanger hook. A hot blade and/or hook be may helpful for chopping the ring in two. Don't heat up the hemostats or else it will destroy the spring-quality of the steel. If you don't have a torch, a lighter will work... but try not to burn your thumb or don't let the lighter melt (pop).

Or if you are super crafty you could [DIY a hot knife](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AD2udt-7Vfo) with a soldering iron and an exacto-blade.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a piece of plastic like this out of the siphon jet by feeding a curved piece of thin wire around the object at the siphon jet entrance.  After a few adjustments on the wire bend, I was able to get the end of the wire around the object and back out the siphon jet hole where I could grab the end of the wire with needle nose pliers.   With the loop all the way around the object I was able to pull on the ends of the wire and the object came out.   Basically I lassoed it and pulled on the lasso.

Before lassoing it, I had tried picks, pliers, and exacto knives with no success.  The plastic object moved easily and was barely visible.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.